# Spring Boot 2.3.0.M4 Layered jar is missing a layer, Docker fails on missing directory

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create a layered docker image with the new layers functionality of Spring Boot 2.3.0. I am using the default layers, and I add these to my docker image.

```
FROM openjdk:14-slim-buster as builder

# Fatjar location, but could be set to different location from command line
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

# Copy fat jar file to current image builder
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar

RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar --enable-preview application.jar extract

FROM openjdk:14-slim-buster
VOLUME /tmp

# Copy all layers from builder stage to current image
COPY --from=builder temp/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder temp/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder temp/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder temp/application/ ./

# Expose current application to port 8080 and 8081
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

ARG JAVA_OPTS=""

# Run the application with JVM configs if any
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", \
"java -server --enable-preview -XX:+UseContainerSupport \
-XX:+AlwaysActAsServerClassMachine -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication ${JAVA_OPTS} \
org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher ${0} ${@}"]
```

However, when I make a release of my application, I don't have any SNAPSHOT dependencies. The extract step doesn't make an snapshot-dependencies folder and Docker is failing because of a missing directory.

```
[ERROR] COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2973e275e2de0cd32dd797d56eaae58c937e4c0fbd0223339a0beb79b187965d/merged/temp/snapshot-dependencies: no such file or directory
[WARNING] An attempt failed, will retry 1 more times
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage (BuildMojo.java:247)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:135)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.tryExecute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:265)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:254)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2973e275e2de0cd32dd797d56eaae58c937e4c0fbd0223339a0beb79b187965d/merged/temp/snapshot-dependencies: no such file or directory
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.LoggingProgressHandler.handleError (LoggingProgressHandler.java:105)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.LoggingProgressHandler.progress (LoggingProgressHandler.java:63)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$BuildProgressHandler.progress (DefaultDockerClient.java:312)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.ProgressStream.tail (ProgressStream.java:77)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$ResponseTailReader.call (DefaultDockerClient.java:2754)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$ResponseTailReader.call (DefaultDockerClient.java:2738)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:832)
```

How can I tell Docker to skip over the missing directory or Spring Boot to even generate a layer even if it is empty?

Comment: i am able to run multi layer build in 2.2.6.RELEASE but it is not going beyond | RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar --enable-preview application.jar extract | it just creates a new container and run the application

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I guess this is already registered as issue in Spring Boot and will be resolved in next Milestone: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20858